# How to get name month in calculated field xtrareport

Tags: devexpress, expression, calculated-field, xtrareport

I'm building a report using xtraReport but I have a problem. I want to get the name of the month using calculated field I did this but I can't get it.

```
FormatString('{0:MMMM}',GetMonth([MYDATE]))
```

The result is MMMM, I'll really apreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a function inside expression when you edit the calculated field

Comment: Sorry for that, man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is how you want to accomplish your task:

[image]

Just click on the glyph for your report control, assign the property to the Expression field and make the format string `{0:MMM}`.

To give you some confidence that this works, here is when I ran it with today's date:

[image]

If you are a purist, here is the code behind:

```
this.xrLabel2.TextFormatString = "{0:MMM}";
```